# Set JButton so that it cannot be pressed or to temporary disable actionListener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have actionListener on JButtons and if I press one of them, I want to somehow disable actionlistener on other ones without removing it.

Is it possible or do I have to remove and than add them actionListener again.

Sorry. I forgot to mention, that i set "button.setPressedIcon(icon)" and i don't want to show this icon. So the mentioned soulution - button.setEnabled(false) wont work.

Comment: Why do you want to disabled the actionlistener, why not disable the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***Is it possible or do i have to remove and than add them actionListener again.***

You can add a boolean variable in the action listener like this:

```
boolean ignoreEvents = false;
```

and then wrap your action-code in

```
if (ignoreEvents)
    return;

ignoreEvents = true;

// your code here...

ignoreEvents = false;
```

Just make sure the code is **properly synchronized**.

---

From a user-interface perspective, you might be better of disabling the buttons instead.

Answer (score 7):

`JButton button = new JButton("hello"); 

button.setEnabled(false)`

That will disable the button, if needed

Answer (score 2):

Besides disabling GUI elements themselves, you might construct them using the `Action` (or `AbstractAction`) class and disable/enable the action instead.  Whatever UI elements were formed from the action will be disabled/enabled accordingly.